# Почему не получается обновить контент блока (комментарии) динамически через ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

1) При загрузке страницы отправляется ajax запрос на внешний файл ajax.php для того, чтобы получить список актуальных комментариев из БД и вывести их на страницу

```
function show() {  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "php/ajax.php",  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#comments_wrapper").html(html);  
                }  
            });  
        }  

        $(document).ready(function(){  
            show();   
        });
```

Эта часть кода работает как надо.

При заполнение форму (новый коммент) и отправке ее, я хочу обновить список комментариев без перезагрузки страницы. Для этого я использую следующий код:

```
var button = $(".form-comment__submit");

        button.click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefult();
            var name = $("#name").value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,''),
                comment = $("#comment").value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'');
            if(name === '' || comment === '') {
                alert('Заполните все поля!');
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({  
                url: "php/ajax.php",  
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: "name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) + "&comment=" + encodeURIComponent(comment),
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#comments_wrapper").html(html);  
                }  
            });
        });
```

В результате при клике происходит переход на страницу ajax.php и в DOM дереве на странице находится обновленный список комментариев (то есть новый коммент попал в базу). Вопрос: почему в первом случае (при загрузке страницы) контент блока обновляется успешно , а во втором происходит переход на ajax.php? Код ajax.php прилагаю

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$db = new SQLite3('../data.sqlite');

if ($_POST) {
    //var_dump($_POST);
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $date = date("d.m.Y");

    $sql = "INSERT into comments (author, content, date) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$comment."', '".$date."')";
    $result = $db->query($sql); 
}


$sql="SELECT * FROM comments";  
$result = $db->query($sql);
$comments = array();

while($data = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
     $comments[] = $data;
}

$avatars = ['img/deadpool.png', 'img/logan.png'];

foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo '<div class="post-item col-12">
            <div class="post-item__header">
                <a href="#" class="post-item__avatar">
                    <img src="'.$avatars[rand(0,1)].'" alt="аватар">
                </a>
                <div class="post-item__text">
                    <h3>'.$comment["author"].'</h3>
                    <span>'.$comment["date"].'</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-item__describe">'.
                $comment['content']
            .'</div>
        </div>';
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите.. Спасибо!

Comment: Потому, что форму с комментом вы сабмитете либо стандартно, без участия ajax вообще, либо не глушите дефолтное поведение кнопки type="submit"  во время отправки ajax (при этом ajax запрос будет улетать а за ним будет происходить переход на файл, который указан для form атрибутом action, методом, указанным атрибутом method).

Comment: Приложите код формы. <br>
В идеале делать событие не с кнопки, а с формы, там её сериализовать проще. <br>
Если делаете отправку через **js**, то action не нужен, он путает вас, и вы думаете что не работает скрипт, на самом деле срабатывает форма. Да и форма в целом не нужна, но если кто-то отключает скрипты, то можно настроить на корректную работу без них

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, кнопка отправки комментария имеет атрибут **type="sumbit"** и находится в форме с указанным атрибутом **action="ajax.php"**.

В таком случае, при отправке формы (а отправка происходит при нажатии на элемент *input type="submit"*), браузер автоматически переадресовывает Вас на страницу, которая указана в форме, в атрибуте action.

Поменяйте **input type="submit"** на **input type="button"**. А в идеале ещё и уберите форму, если отправка комментариев и их загрузка на страницу происходит через AJAX-запросы.

```
<form class="commentForm" action="ajax.php"> ===> <div class="commentForm">
    ...
    <input type="submit" ...> ===> <input type="button" ...>
    ...
</form> ===> </div>
```

Формы нужны для того, чтобы страница могла передать запросы непосредственно в PHP-скрипт. В случае, если Вы используете AJAX, формы не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

**var button = $(".form-comment__submit");** у Вас input type="submit"?  Если да, то поменяйте на `<button class="form-comment__submit"></button>`